# Random character generator with a range of (A..Z, 0..9) and punctuation

Tags: java, android, random

I need to create a random character generator that return a single character. The character should range within the letters of the alphabet, numbers 0 through 9, and some characters like ,.?/-. Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: First.  What language do you think you're going to use?  Second.  Please post your best guess as to how you'd do this.  This is not "do my homework for me.com".

Comment: Add a language to your tags before this gets closed.

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Thanks for your blunt answer. The language is Java. I am using the Android SDK. I was going to generate numbers and get the ASCII values of the numbers for each character. I don't need my homework done. I'm 67 years old and probably been programming longer than you've been alive.

Comment: Added the tags to your question.

Answer (score 41):

The easiest is to do the following:

- Create a `String alphabet` with the chars that you want.
- Say `N = alphabet.length()`
- Then we can ask a [`java.util.Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) for an [`int x = nextInt(N)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)
- `alphabet.charAt(x)` is a random char from the alphabet

Here's an example:

```
    final String alphabet = "0123456789ABCDE";
    final int N = alphabet.length();

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

See below link :
http://www.asciitable.com/

```
public static char randomSeriesForThreeCharacter() {
    Random r = new Random();
    char random_3_Char = (char) (48 + r.nextInt(47));
    return random_3_Char;
}
```

Now you can generate a character at one time of calling.

Answer (score 5):

1. Pick a random number between [0, x), where x is the number of different symbols. Hopefully the choice is uniformly chosen and not predictable :-)
2. Now choose the symbol representing x.
3. Profit!

I would start reading up [Pseudorandomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) and then some common [Pseudo-random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators). Of course, your language hopefully already has a suitable "random" function :-)

Comment: +1 for using a reasonable step -> step -> profit!!! scheme when facing this kind of question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is code for secure, easy, but a little bit more expensive session identifiers.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator
{

  private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

  public String nextSessionId()
  {
    return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? RandomStringUtils from Apache Commons has functions to which you can specify the character set from which characters are generated. You can take what you need to your app:

http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.java.htm

Answer (score 2):

You should first make a String that holds all of the letters/numbers that you want.
Then, make a Random. e. g. `Random rnd = new Random;`
Finally, make something that actually gets a random character from your String containing your alphabet.
For example,

```
import java.util.Random;

public class randomCharacter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ?/.,";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        char char = alphabet.charAt(rnd.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
        // do whatever you want with the character
    }
}
```

See [this](http://programming.guide/java/generate-random-character.html).
It's where I got this info from.

Answer (score 1):

Using some simple command line (bash scripting):

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-z0-9,.?/\-' | head -c 30 | xargs
t315,qeqaszwz6kxv?761rf.cj/7gc

$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-z0-9,.?/\-' | head -c 1 | xargs
f
```

- cat /dev/urandom: get a random stream of char from the kernel
- tr: keep only char char we want
- head: take only the first `n` chars
- xargs: just for adding a `'\n'` char

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
int n = random.nextInt(69) + 32;
if (n > 96) {
    n += 26;
}
char c = (char) n;
```

I guess it depends which punctuation you want to include, but this should generate a random character including all of the punctuation on this ASCII table. Basically, I've generated a random int from 32 - 96 or 123 - 126, which I have then casted to a char, which gives the ASCII equivalent of that number. Also, make sure you`import java.util.Random`

Answer (score 0):

random char
             package com.company;

```
         import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

         public class Main {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
            // write your code here
                char hurufBesar =randomSeriesForThreeCharacter(65,90);
                char angka = randomSeriesForThreeCharacter(48,57);
                char simbol = randomSeriesForThreeCharacter(33,47);
                char hurufKecil= randomSeriesForThreeCharacter(97,122);
                char angkaLagi = randomSeriesForThreeCharacter(48,57);

                System.out.println(hurufBesar+" "+angka+" "+simbol+" "+hurufKecil+" "+angkaLagi);
            }

            public static char randomSeriesForThreeCharacter(int min,int max) {
                int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
                char random_3_Char = (char) (randomNumber);
                return random_3_Char;
             }
         }
```